# How do I use both form_with and simple_form_for in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating an rgb table using a gem called **jquery-minicolors-rails**. However, github only shows examples for **simple_form_for**. I am using **form_with**.

Just insert **simple_form_for** in **form_with** and it does not respond when you press submit.

**_form_html.erb (Case 1)**

```
<%= simple_form_for @balloon do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :color, as: :minicolors, input_html: {data: {
      minicolors: {theme: :bootstrap, position: :right}}} 
  %>
<% end %>
```

> Case 1 does not respond when submit is pressed

**_form_html.erb (Case 2)**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :color %>
    <%= f.text_area :color, as: :minicolors, input_html: {data: {
        minicolors: {theme: :bootstrap, position: :right}}} %>
  </div>
```

> Case 2 only shows text_area without rgb table

Thank you for reading and I look forward to lots of advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_with` not support futures from `simple_form_for`. So, in case 2, `as` and `input_html` do nothing as invalid attributes. In this case, you must use a script to initialize color picker. Also, gem replace `input` to the picker, not `textarea`

```
#field
<%= f.text_field :color, class: 'color-picker' %>

#coffee script
$ -> $('.color-picker').minicolors theme: 'bootstrap'
```

Also, in each case you need to add submit button `<%= f.submit %>` or write a script, that would send form when color selected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tried to run it, but only text_area appears and gem does not run.
The script code was written in home.coffee.
I also want to submit the title, content, and color field values ​​in one submit.

Comment: @yori, `$('.color-picker')` there was missing a dot. I updated my answer, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

You've not posted your actual code for the submit button so impossible to be certain, however form_tag uses

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

While simple_form_for uses

```
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

Try adding f.button :submit to your simple_form_for and it should work

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I want to submit the title, content, and value of the color field in one submit.